# meaning of the word ''heuristically'' in this text

Tags: word-meaning

What is the meaning of the word heuristically in this text? (I had to copy the screenshot because of the mathematical formulas)
[image]

I consulted a number of available dictionaries and the possible meanings I found for the word **heuristic** are these:
1-(Mathematics) (of a method of solving problems) one for which no algorithm exists and which therefore depends on inductive reasoning from past experience of similar problems

2-proceeding to a solution by trial and error or by rules that are only loosely defined

Which of these meanings is correct (if any)?

Comment: You're asking about how the textbook evaluates n^2/x^2. That seems like more of a question for Math Stack Exchange than for ELL. (It might also be hard for the math folks to provide an answer without seeing equation (1).)

Comment: @abs, you should provide a link to an online copy of that page, in addition to the screenshot, but it might mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_(computer_science) --- more complete questions get better answers and are more useful to more people.